# Connect LG Optimus 2X to Windows/Ubuntu via Bluetooth/Data Cable to use Internet

Tags: bluetooth, linux, internet, windows, lg-optimus-2x

I want to connect my LG Optimus 2X (P990) to my PC to use the Internet. 
I tried using the LG PC Suite 4 available for windows, but it crashes as soon as I make a connection with my phone. And, There's no option in the suite to use the Internet connection from the phone.

Also, I can't get Ubuntu to detect a connection from my phone (both Bluetooth and Data Cable).

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EasyTether](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_polyclef&hl=en) is the easiest way to share your phone wireless internet with your computer. You install the program on your phone, set up the drivers (which can be found [here](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.html)) and run. To enable easytether, check the top box on the application screen. Easy as that!

*After you install the drivers:*

For Ubuntu:

- start a terminal window
- type `easytether connect`
- it will connect, and give you another command that you can type into another terminal window to see status information about your connection.

**NOTE: the original terminal window you open (that you typed `easytether connect` into) must stay open while you are using the connection**

For Windows:

- right click the Easytether logo in the taskbar (lower right hand side, by the clock)
- choose `connect via (big number here)`
- you're connected!

Comment: mmhmm! glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work with your device, but I used to use [Android Wired Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wired-tether/) the couple times I needed to use my phones data connection. It does require root, so I don't know if that is an option for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

it worked out of the box in ubuntu 12.

While installing the deb package, I got the following error message in /var/log/syslog.  But, this warning can be ignored.

```
May 18 22:49:29 dev01 udevd[375]: invalid ENV attribute, 'DRIVER' can not be set /lib/udev/rules.d/65-easytether.rules:1
```

I had installed easy tether lite application in my android phone following the instructions from the application.

To connect to the phone, I did:

```
sudar@dev01 /opt/testing/lens/bin $ easytether connect  80A354043043422239
trying legacy service port (this is not an error)
connected as easytether0, wait while network-manager configures it

or run 'sudo dhclient easytether0' if you do not use network-manager

press Ctrl-C when you are done with the connection
```

The network-manager was able to pick up the device immediately and configured a dhcp address automatically.

```
easytether0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:54:74:68:72  
      inet addr:192.168.117.2  Bcast:192.168.117.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::54ff:fe74:6872/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
      RX bytes:1008908 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:418292 (418.2 KB)
```

When I check the default route, it was properly setup to the tether device.

```
sudar@dev01 /opt/testing/lens/bin $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.117.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 easytether0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 easytether0
192.168.117.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 easytether0
```

Overall, it is very easy to get connected. :)